# Weird Normal Map? How can i fix this

Tags: normal-map

So i got into blender today an i want to bake some textures and i dont know why but the normal map just doesnt want to work properly. I tried for 2 hours but i cant fix this. The map looks really weird it has some sharp edges if you look on the pictures. What did I do wrong. Is it something with the UV mapping. I did the smart uv

[[image: Weird Normal Map?][1]]

Comment: you will need to share more details about your problem... settings you tried, settings you have, or even better your blend file so we can find where is the problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your texture resolution is too low for the detail you're trying to capture.

Furthermore, you have some very steep angles and these typically can mess up normal mapping.